# Japanese in python function

Tags: python, internationalization

I wrote a function in Python which is used to tell me whether the two words are similar or not.

Now I want to pass Japanese text in my same function. It is giving error "not a ascii character." I tried using utf-8 encoding, but then it giving the same error

```
Non-ASCII character '\xe3' in file
```

Is there any way to do that? I cant generate the msg file for that since the 2 keyword will be not be constant.

Here goes the code

```
def filterKeyword(keyword, adText, filterType):
if (filterType == 'contains'):
    try :
        adtext = str.lower(adText)
        keyword = str.lower(keyword)
        if (adtext.find(keyword)!=-1):
            return '0'
    except:
        return '1'
if (filterType == 'exact'):
    var = cmp(str.lower(adText), str.lower(keyword))
    if(var == 0 ):
        return '0'

return '1'
```

I have used the following:

```
filterKeyword(unicode('ポケモン').encode("utf-8"), unicode('黄色のポケモン').encode("utf-8"), 'contains')

filterKeyword('ポケモン'.encode("utf-8"), '黄色のポケモン'.encode("utf-8"), 'contains')
```

Both of them are giving the error.

Comment: Let me guess as to what you code looks like.  After I'm done guessing what your code looks like, I'll try and post and answer based on guessing.  If you want a helpful answer, you could -- perhaps -- provide the code which isn't working.

Comment: You might want to use Python 3.0+ instead of Python 2.6+ for this.

Comment: @Michael: 2.x is perfectly capable of handling this.

Comment: Post the complete error you're getting, not just a single line.

Comment: I understand it was extremely mild, but please don't post profanity in any language on SO.  I'm personally not offended by it, but it was enough to get flagged and this just isn't the place for it.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: What does the Japanese text read now?

Comment: @Gumbo: According to Google Translate, it now says "Pokemon" and "Pokemon yellow."  I sincerely hope those phrases don't translate into something filthy in Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def filterKeyword(keyword, adText, filterType):
    # same as yours

filterKeyword(u'ポケモン', u'黄色のポケモン', 'contains')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not do this:

```
adtext = str.lower(adText)
keyword = str.lower(keyword)
```

Please do this:

```
adtext= adText.lower()
keyword = keyword.lower()
```

Please do not do this:

```
cmp(str.lower(adText), str.lower(keyword))
```

Please do this:

```
return adText.lower() == keyword.lower()
```

Please do not do this:

```
try:
    # something
except:
    # handler
```

Please provide a specific exception.  A generic (superclass) like `Exception` is fine.  There are some non-exception errors which you cannot meaningfully catch.

```
try:
    # something
except Exception:
    # handler
```

Also, it's really unlikely that catching an exception would return True.

Please do not do this:

```
return '1' 
return '0'
```

It's unlikely you want to return a character.  It's more likely you want to return True or False.

```
return True
return False
```

Your code will work, if you do things properly.

```
>>> u'ポケモン'.lower() == u'黄色のポケモン'.lower()
False
>>> u'ポケモン'.lower() in  u'黄色のポケモン'.lower()
True
```

Comment: You missed the bare `except`.

Comment: the code is not working only half .It is giving exception when i tries to find


 if (adtext.find(keyword)!=-1):

Comment: @ha22109.  I posted the `in` operator for a reason.  What do you think that reason is?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UTF-8. Use [`unicode`s](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Comment: UTF-8 is a representation of unicode, so that doesn't make sense. Also, your link is just the opening slide and doesn't have any useful info.

Comment: @Michael: It only doesn't make sense if you haven't read the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

In one of the first two lines of your script. This way the interpreter will know what encoding is used for the code and strings in it.

And use Unicode strings wherever possible. If you have luck the function may work well with the Unicode (e.g. `u"something…"` instead of `"something..."`) arguments  even if it was not written with Unicode in mind.

Comment: it is giving me error

UnicodeDecodeError
"'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to note well:

`unicode('ポケモン')` (a non-unicode string constant passed to the unicode() constructor)

IS NOT THE SAME AS

`u'ポケモン'` (a unicode string constant)