# Unable to display Japanese (UTF-8) characters in email body with webbrowser

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-webbrowser

I am reading text from two different .txt files and concatenating them together. Then add that to a body of the email through by using `webbrowser`.

One text file is English characters (ascii) and the other Japanese (UTF-8). The text will display fine if I write it to a text file. But if I use `webbrowser` to insert the text into an email body the Japanese text displays as question marks.

I have tried running the script on multiple machines that have different mail clients as their defaults. Initially I thought maybe that was the issue, but that does not appear to be. Thunderbird and Mail (MacOSX) display question marks.

```
Hello. Today is 2014-05-09

????????????????2014-05-09????
```

I have looked at similar issues around on SO but they have not solved the issue.

- [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in
  position 20: ordinal not in
  range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20?rq=1)
- [Japanese in python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522408/japanese-in-python-function)
- [Printing out Japanese (Chinese) characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352234/printing-out-japanese-chinese-characters)
- [python utf-8 japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908544/python-utf-8-japanese)

Is there a way to have the Japanese (UTF-8) display in the body of an email created with `webbrowser` in python? I could use the `email` functionality but the requirement is the script needs to open the default mail client and insert all the information.

The code and text files I am using are below. I have simplified it to focus on the issue.

*email-template.txt*

```
Hello. Today is {{date}}
```

*email-template-jp.txt*

```
こんにちは。今日は {{date}} です。
```

Python Script

```
#
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

import sys
import re
import os
import glob
import webbrowser
import codecs,sys

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)

# vars
date_range = sys.argv[1:][0]

email_template_en   = "email-template.txt"
email_template_jp   = "email-template-jp.txt"   
email_to_send       = "email-to-send.txt"       # finished email is saved here

# Default values for the composed email that will be opened
mail_list           = "test@test.com"
cc_list             = "test1@test.com, test2@test.com"
subject             = "Email Subject"

# Open email templates and insert the date from the parameters sent in
try:
    f_en = open(email_template_en, "r")
    f_jp = codecs.open(email_template_jp, "r", "UTF-8")
    try:
        email_content_en = f_en.read()
        email_content_jp = f_jp.read()

        email_en = re.sub(r'{{date}}', date_range, email_content_en) 
        email_jp = re.sub(r'{{date}}', date_range, email_content_jp).encode("UTF-8") 
        # this throws an error
        # UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
        # email_en_jp = (email_en + email_jp).encode("UTF-8") 
        email_en_jp = (email_en + email_jp)
    finally:
        f_en.close()
        f_jp.close()
    pass
except Exception, e:
    raise e

# Open the default mail client and fill in all the information
try:
    f = open(email_to_send, "w")
    try:
        f.write(email_en_jp)
        # Does not send Japanese text to the mail client. But will write to the .txt file fine. Unsure why.
        webbrowser.open("mailto:%s?subject=%s&cc=%s&body=%s" %(mail_list, subject, cc_list, email_en_jp), new=1) # open mail client with prefilled info
    finally:
        f.close()
    pass
except Exception, e:
    raise e
```

edit: Forgot to add I am using Python 2.7.1

Comment: I think email content that isn't pure ASCII must be encoded as [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), probably using BASE64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2**: Found a workable solution after all.

Replace your **webbrowser** call with this.

```
import subprocess
[... other code ...]
arg = "mailto:%s?subject=%s&cc=%s&body=%s" % (mail_list, subject, cc_list, email_en_jp)
subprocess.call(["open", arg])
```

This will open your default email client on MacOS. For other OSes please replace "open" in the subprocess line with the proper executable.

---

**EDIT**: I looked into it a bit more and Mark's comment above made me read the [RFC (2368)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) for mailto URL scheme.

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
>   body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
>   the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
>   primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
>   actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
>   messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

And a bit further down:

> 8-bit characters in mailto URLs are forbidden. MIME encoded words (as
>   defined in [RFC2047]) are permitted in header values, but not for any
>   part of a "body" hname."

So it looks like this is not possible as per RFC, although that makes me question why the JavaScript solution in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/R6YGK/6/) provided by naota works at all.

---

I leave my previous answer as is below, although it does not work.

---

I have run into same issues with Python 2.7.x quite a couple of times now and every time a different solution somehow worked.

So here are several suggestions that may or may not work, as I haven't tested them.

a) Force unicode strings:

```
webbrowser.open(u"mailto:%s?subject=%s&cc=%s&body=%s" % (mail_list, subject, cc_list, email_en_jp), new=1)
```

Notice the small u right after the opening ( and before the ".

b) Force the regex to use unicode:

```
email_jp = re.sub(ur'{{date}}', date_range, email_content_jp).encode("UTF-8") 
# or maybe
email_jp = re.sub(ur'{{date}}', date_range, email_content_jp)
```

c) Another idea regarding the regex, try compiling it first with the re.UNICODE flag, before applying it.

```
pattern = re.compile(ur'{{date}}', re.UNICODE)
```

d) Not directly related, but I noticed you write the combined text via the normal **open** method. Try using the **codecs.open** here as well.

```
f = codecs.open(email_to_send, "w", "UTF-8")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your edit at the top worked like a charm. It is not possible to use webbrowser with mixed characters. Thank you!